# Titanium Appcelerator Mapview Takes a Long Time to Open

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I am creating an iOS app in Titanium Appcelerator that contains a dashboard window and 2 additional windows. One of them contains a mapview that takes ~3 seconds to load, which is a long time to be looking at a blank screen.

In the Appcelerator forums, [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/97671/geolocation-refreshing-to-current-location) post someone has posted asking how to refresh to a user's position, only when it changes by a certain amount, which I have implemented. My current implementation is as follows:

1. Set the distance filter so that it only refreshes on major moves

   ```
   Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;
   ```
2. Create a mapview at an insignificant starting location (0,0) and add it to the window

   ```
   var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
       mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
       region: {latitude: 0, longitude: 0, latitudeDelta:0.05, longitudeDelta:0.05},
       animate:false,
       regionFit:true,
       userLocation:false
   });

   win.add(mapview);
   ```
3. Get the users location and set the mapview's location to it

   ```
   //Should only go once
   Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e)
   {
       if (e.error)
       {
           alert('Cannot get your current location');
           return;
       }

       var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
       var latitude = e.coords.latitude;
       var altitude = e.coords.altitude;
       var heading = e.coords.heading;
       var accuracy = e.coords.accuracy;
       var speed = e.coords.speed;
       var timestamp = e.coords.timestamp;
       var altitudeAccuracy = e.coords.altitudeAccuracy;

       var current = {
               latitude : latitude,
               longitude : longitude,
               latitudeDelta : .05,
               longitudeDelta : .05
           };
       mapview.setLocation(current);
       mapview.userLocation = true;
   });
   ```

I just want the map to load fast. If it takes a few seconds to pinpoint the user's location, that's fine. But having the user look at a blank screen for 3 seconds is terrible. Is there a way around this?

I have also set:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
```

if it makes a difference.

**EDIT:** I commented out the part where I am getting the users location and the map still takes the same amount of time to load. I think the problem has to do with the fact that I am opening my map.js file before I create it.

In my app.js file, I call map.open(). Then at the top of my map.js file, I do:

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
```

and then I construct the map and add it. I don't know of a way to keep my architecture but preload the map. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any Titanium.Geolocation method or event-listener. Try with user location true only on mapview it reflects the user location on map.

**Firstly just open MAP Window.**

Distance filter works fine with eventlistener of Titanium.Geolocation. Could you please share your code? Then I will suggest you a proper solution.

If you want use Titanium.Geolocation method or event-listener to change the location of map.

**Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosstion()** put it into setInterval function that calls function(Titanium.Geolocation) after a particular time interval.Use this functionality after open map window.

**Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',function(**){
...
});
Use Distance filter , it fires after after a particular distance.